# Why treats PostgreSQL a hyphen (~) like a space when sorting a row?

Tags: postgresql, sorting

In a simple table in PostgreSQL

```
CREATE TABLE "SOMESCHEMA".newtable (
    col1 varchar NULL
);
```

I inserted three rows with the values

```
"A 1"
"A~2"
"A 3"
```

Whe I make a query like

```
SELECT col1 FROM "SOMESCHEMA".newtable order by col1 desc;
```

the results are ordered in the following way:

```
"A 3"
"A~2"
"A 1"
```

Why isn't `A~2` be placed on top or bottom ?
Do I have to change a setting ? The collation of the column is `en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: Try `order by col1 collate "POSIX"`.  Please see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html

Answer (score 1):

With a natural language collation (no matter if it is a libc collation like `de_AT.utf8` or an ICU collation like `de-DE-x-icu`), the comparison happens in different levels. For the first level, all non-alphabetic characters are considered equal. If two strings compare equal on the first level, the next level is used to break the tie. Now space and tilde are considered equal on the high levels, which explains the result you see.

Use the binary collation to get the result you want:

```
... ORDER BY col1 COLLATE "C"
```

Answer (score -1):

In ASCII table, the tilde character is represented by the decimal code 126, which is higher than the decimal codes of digits and capital/lowercase letters. However, when PostgreSQL uses UTF-8 for collation, it treats the tilde character differently in order to conform to linguistic rules.

The tilde character is not generally used in English language text, so in many UTF-8 collations it's treated as a secondary or tertiary difference. In other words, it's less significant than a difference in letters or even accents on letters.

Comment: Thanks for explaning. Which collation could be used so that this case is treated like a real difference ?

Comment: Probably `C` collation, something like `SELECT col1 FROM "SOMESCHEMA".newtable ORDER BY col1 COLLATE "C" DESC;`

Comment: UTF-8 is not a collation.